# Identifying ID of a duplicated row combinations in a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table in SQL Server, representing the "built" of my products. A product can be built from the combination of a single or multiple `MODEL_ID`, with their respective `MODEL_YEAR` (nullable since I do not have always have this info), and `QUANTITY_PER_PRODUCT`.

```
CREATE TABLE [TD].[PRODUCT_BUILD]
(
    [PRODUCT_BUILD_ID]     int identity NOT NULL ,
    [PRODUCT_ID]           int NOT NULL ,
    [MODEL_ID]             int NOT NULL ,
    [MODEL_YEAR]           smallint NULL ,
    [QUANTITY_PER_PRODUCT] tinyint NOT NULL ,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_PRODUCT_BUILT] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PRODUCT_BUILD_ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_727] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([PRODUCT_ID])  REFERENCES [TD].[PRODUCT]([PRODUCT_ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_730] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([MODEL_ID])  REFERENCES [TD].[MODEL]([MODEL_ID])
)
```

Assuming I am given a `PRODUCT_ID` value as variable `@ProductID`, I would like to find the first found `PRODUCT_ID`, if it exists, of a duplicated combinations of `MODEL_ID`, `MODEL_YEAR` and `QUANTITY_PER_PRODUCT` matching the exact combination associated with `@ProductID`.

With `@ProductID = 99` and the following table, I would like a SELECT returning `PRODUCT_ID = 51`.

```
+------------------+------------+----------+------------+----------------------+
| PRODUCT_BUILD_ID | PRODUCT_ID | MODEL_ID | MODEL_YEAR | QUANTITY_PER_PRODUCT |
+------------------+------------+----------+------------+----------------------+
|                1 |         24 |       26 |            |                    1 |
|                2 |         50 |       26 |       2017 |                    1 |
|                3 |         50 |       34 |       2019 |                    2 |
|                4 |         51 |       26 |            |                    1 |
|                5 |         51 |       34 |       2019 |                    2 |
|                6 |         99 |       26 |            |                    1 |
|                7 |         99 |       34 |       2019 |                    2 |
|                8 |         13 |       26 |            |                    2 |
|                9 |         13 |       34 |       2019 |                    2 |
|               10 |          4 |       26 |            |                    1 |
+------------------+------------+----------+------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Hint: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()`

Comment: @marc_s Of course, sorry fixed it, the code was generated from a buggy third-party tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @ProductID INT = 99

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES PRODUCT_BUILD_ID , PRODUCT_ID , MODEL_ID , MODEL_YEAR , QUANTITY_PER_PRODUCT FROM (
    SELECT T1.* ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY T1.PRODUCT_ID ) AS CNT1, T2.CNT2  FROM [PRODUCT_BUILD] T1 
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT *,  COUNT(*) OVER() AS CNT2 FROM [PRODUCT_BUILD] WHERE PRODUCT_ID = @ProductID ) AS T2 
                ON T1.MODEL_ID  = T2.MODEL_ID AND 
                   ISNULL(T1.MODEL_YEAR,'') = ISNULL(T2.MODEL_YEAR,'') AND 
                   T1.QUANTITY_PER_PRODUCT = T2.QUANTITY_PER_PRODUCT 
) X
WHERE CNT1 = CNT2
ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID
```

Result:

```
PRODUCT_BUILD_ID PRODUCT_ID  MODEL_ID    MODEL_YEAR QUANTITY_PER_PRODUCT
---------------- ----------- ----------- ---------- --------------------
4                51          26          NULL       1
5                51          34          2019       2
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would by with a `WHERE EXISTS` clause. This will return all of the values where there's a duplicate matching your passed parameter. If you only want one, you could add a `TOP (1)` to the outer `SELECT`.

```
SELECT <TOP (1)> --<---Optional
  PRODUCT_ID
FROM 
  [TD].[PRODUCT_BUILD] as pb
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM 
    [TD].[PRODUCT_BUILD] as pb2
  WHERE
    pb2.PRODUCT_ID = @ProductID
    AND pb.MODEL_ID = pb2.MODEL_ID
    AND pb.MODEL_YEAR = pb2.MODEL_YEAR
    AND pb.QUANTITY_PER_PRODUCT = pb2.QUANTITY_PER_PRODUCT
    AND pb.PRODUCT_ID <> pb2.PRODUCT_ID
)
```